# How can I properly access my EF foreign key column straight after it has been added?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I have a basic notification system working on my site and I have started to make it work in real-time with SignalR but I'm having trouble accessing my foreign key to the user table.

I have the following code in one of my pages that generates a new Notification object

```
Notification NewNotification = new Notification
{
    UserToId = u.UserId,
    NotificationText = "some text"
};
db.Notifications.Add(NewNotification);
db.SaveChanges();
string name = NewNotification.UserFrom.DisplayName;
```

On the last line I get `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

When I pass the NewNotification through SignalR to the client and try to access `NewNotification.UserFrom.DisplayName` the js console tells me that NewNotification.UserFrom is undefined. This happens despite me being able to access it on the layout page after the Notifications have been added.

The relevant parts of my model for my Notification is as follows

```
public class Notification
{
    public Notification()
    {
        this.UserFromId = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;
    }

    [Key]
    public int NotificationId { get; set; }

    public int UserToId { get; set; }
    public int UserFromId { get; set; }

    public virtual UserProfile UserTo { get; set; }
    public virtual UserProfile UserFrom { get; set; }

    [MaxLength]
    public string NotificationText { get; set; }
}
```

And then my db context has the following to set up the foreign key relationship

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Notification>()
                .HasRequired(n => n.UserFrom)
                .WithMany(u => u.NotificationsFrom)
                .HasForeignKey(n => n.UserFromId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Notification>()
                .HasRequired(n => n.UserTo)
                .WithMany(u => u.NotificationsTo)
                .HasForeignKey(n => n.UserToId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```

---

#### The question is:

How can I access `UserFrom.DisplayName` of the notification just after it's been created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is likely that your entity is not being refreshed after the save. you can either

1) reacquire it from the datastore with another query. If Notification has some sort of Identity column, it will be updated on SaveChanges() on your `NewNotification` object. That id can be used to retrieve the object. (Something like `NewNotification = db.Notifications.Single(x => x.Id == NewNotification.Id)`

2) If you hate the above option, you can do something like this: 
`((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.ClientWins, NewNotification);` This will update your NewNotification object. Not pretty, but I ran into an issue similar to this recently and it worked for me.

3) since you have the userid in scope already, I would consider doing a `db.Users.Single(x => x.UserId == u.UserId).DisplayName`

If you want to access the User through the NewNotification object, I personally like option 2 because it becomes a bit clearer what your intentions are.... You want to refresh your NewNotifications object against the database and you want whatever is in the Client that doesn't match your object to "WIN".

I think option 3 is perhaps the cleanest, but its your call!

Comment: The first option gave me a null reference exception as well when I try to access `UserFrom.DisplayName`. The second option gave me `System.Data.Linq.Refreshmode does not contain a defintion for ClientWins` So I had to use the third option you gave me which isn't really what I wanted but it gets the job done.

Comment: different versions of entity framework may handle option 2 differently than others.... I guess I would investigate. Glad to hear option 3 worked out :)